# Jasper Report integration in Primefaces

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, jasper-reports

I am posting a code snippet which worked well on other forms to print Jasperreport as Pdf.

```
<p:commandButton id="cmdPrint" value="Print"
    actionListener="#{receiptMB.print()}"
    disabled="#{receiptMB.chkSave == false}" process="@this" />
```

Backing Bean code snippet :

```
public void print(){

        try
        {
        JRBeanCollectionDataSource beanCollectionDataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(getObjPrintList());

        String  reportPath=  FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRealPath("/reports/Receipt.jasper");     

        JasperPrint jasperPrint=JasperFillManager.fillReport(reportPath,getReportParameters(), beanCollectionDataSource);  

        HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse();
        httpServletResponse.setContentType("application / pdf");
        httpServletResponse.addHeader("Content-disposition", "inline; filename=Receipt_" +objPrint.getDateNp()+".pdf");
        ServletOutputStream servletOutputStream = httpServletResponse.getOutputStream();

        servletOutputStream.write(JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf(jasperPrint));
        servletOutputStream.flush();
        servletOutputStream.close();
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().renderResponse();
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
        }
        catch(JRException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

The above code is working well on other forms but it is not working in a particular form which is a Dialog.It gives no error but, also it doesn't give any output.
I went around with some solutions but no work.

Comment: Shouldn't use an ajax request to generate the output. Set `ajax="false"` on the command button

Comment: I will try and report.

Comment: Setting 'ajax="false"' didn't call the print method.

Comment: Then something else must be wrong (between the `disabled` attribute  kicking in and a general conversion/validation error). Using a non-ajax command button is not optional. See this answer also http://stackoverflow.com/a/13696243/1530938

Comment: I added **immediate="true"**, it worked.

Comment: And one more thing, I want to know that how to autoclose or hide the Dialog after clicking the Print button ??

Comment: @SudeepShakya Please open another question for that. i will provide you the answer. This actually doesnt relate to the original question.